# Linux fails at creating an tar file for a backup

Tags: linux, backup, git, tar, ruby

So I want to make a backup of git. I am using this script to do this (here:https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md). But creating the tar file always fails at the end.

```
root@gitlab-test git/gitlab# sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production --trace                                                                                
** Invoke gitlab:backup:create (first_time)                                                                                                                                                   
** Invoke environment (first_time)                                                                                                                                                            
** Execute environment                                                                                                                                                                        
** Execute gitlab:backup:create                                                                                                                                                               
** Invoke gitlab:backup:db:create (first_time)                                                                                                                                                
** Invoke environment                                                                                                                                                                         
** Execute gitlab:backup:db:create                                                                                                                                                            
Dumping database ... 
Dumping MySQL database gitlab_production ... [DONE]
done
** Invoke gitlab:backup:repo:create (first_time)                                                                                                                                              
** Invoke environment                                                                                                                                                                         
** Execute gitlab:backup:repo:create                                                                                                                                                          
Dumping repositories ...
 * gitlab-admin/test ... [DONE]
 * gitlab-admin/test.wiki ...  [SKIPPED]
done
** Invoke gitlab:backup:uploads:create (first_time)                                                                                                                                           
** Invoke environment                                                                                                                                                                         
** Execute gitlab:backup:uploads:create                                                                                                                                                       
Dumping uploads ... 
done
** Invoke gitlab:backup:builds:create (first_time)                                                                                                                                            
** Invoke environment                                                                                                                                                                         
** Execute gitlab:backup:builds:create                                                                                                                                                        
Dumping builds ... 
done
** Invoke gitlab:backup:artifacts:create (first_time)                                                                                                                                         
** Invoke environment                                                                                                                                                                         
** Execute gitlab:backup:artifacts:create                                                                                                                                                     
Dumping artifacts ... 
done
** Invoke gitlab:backup:lfs:create (first_time)                                                                                                                                               
** Invoke environment                                                                                                                                                                         
** Execute gitlab:backup:lfs:create                                                                                                                                                           
Dumping lfs objects ... 
done
Creating backup archive: 1469611232_gitlab_backup.tar ... tar: uploads.tar.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory                                                                         
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors                                                                                                                                       
creating archive 1469611232_gitlab_backup.tar failed
Backup failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's trying to include uploads.tar.gz (attachments) but isn't found.

Try skipping it:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create SKIP=uploads RAILS_ENV=production --trace
```